# Sequelize two sources of truth ( migration and model )

Tags: sequelize.js

Why sequelize has 2 sources of truth, so if you wanted to do a migration, you should also edit the model which is frustrating, what is the proper way to deal with that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In local environment, you are probably use a "forceUpdate" option (I don't know the real name) from Sequelize to see your changes in your db editing your models directly. Models are just defining db schema with properties for your tables, associations between them... Often in local environment it's faster, and more comfortable to use this option for adding more features.

But in production environment, the "forceUpdate" option has to be disabled so as to avoid to loose data refreshing your database models. So migration files are the way to update your db schema and offer a way to rollback your changes if there is a problem.